# tensorflow how to reduce high "device-to-device" load

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, gpu

I profiled a model that I am running and the vast majority of the time in each step (295 of 320ms) is being taken up by "device-to-device" operations (see image). I assume this means loading data from my cpu onto my gpu and back is the bottleneck.

I am running this on a single machine. The data is stored on an SSD and being fed into a GPU.
I am using tensorflow's tf.data.Dataset API and doing all the recommended things like prefetching and `num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`

My questions are:
(1) Is my assumption correct?
(2) How do I reduce this huge burden on my model?

[Tensorboard Profiling Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfUyh.png)

Comment: Did you train the model with distributed strategy? If so, I think the device-to-device means GPU-to-GPU communication on parameters updating. If you trained the model in multiple machine, that's mostly due to the network bandwidth limitation. Profiler also provide some suggestions about how to deal with the bottleneck at the bottom right of the profiler page.

Comment: thanks for the comment, no it's on a single machine, clarification has been added to the question.

Comment: Did you use tf.data.Dataset for input pipeline? If so, did you prefetch the data at the end of pipeline? Maybe [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance_analysis) would help you.

Comment: thanks alexander, I am using tf.data.Dataset and pre-fetching religiously. I'll add that to the question

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer but it's something; by using tensorflow's [mixed precision training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision) I was able to reduce the "device-to-device" time to ~ 145ms. This is still an immense burden compared to everything else profiled and I'd love to be able to reduce it further.

I don't know why this helped either. I assume that mp-training means smaller numbers of bytes are being passed around so maybe that helps.

[image: New Tensorboard Profiling Overview]